# Primevue calendar not displaying icons in my vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Primevue calendar not displaying icons in my vue application.

```
<template>
  <Calendar v-model="value" />
</template>

<script>
import Calendar from 'primevue/calendar';

export default {

  name: 'primeCalender',
  data() {
        return {
            value: null
        }
  },
  components: {
    Calendar
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Please refer below Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpfJT.png